resultset within begin transaction statement throws error - snowflake
This works well
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FAIR_PROC(
    DATABASE_REF VARCHAR
    , RUN_ID INTEGER
    , TASKID VARCHAR
    , RECORD_UPDATED NUMBER
    , RECORD_INSERTED NUMBER
    , RECORD_DELETED NUMBER)
RETURNS VARCHAR 
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
DECLARE 
V_PROCEDURE_NAME VARCHAR(50) := 'FAIR_PROC';
V_TASK_METRICS_TBL_REF VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
    V_TASK_METRICS_TBL_REF := :DATABASE_REF || '.METADATA_OPS.TASK_METRICS';
    LET RES RESULTSET;
    RES := (INSERT INTO IDENTIFIER(:V_TASK_METRICS_TBL_REF)(RUN_ID
        , TASKID 
        , RECORD_UPDATED
        , RECORD_INSERTED
        , RECORD_DELETED) 
    VALUES(:RUN_ID
        , :TASKID 
        , :RECORD_UPDATED
        , :RECORD_INSERTED
        , :RECORD_DELETED));
    RETURN 'SUCCESS';
END;


But below procedure does not if I put in begin transaction statement. It throws following error

SQL compilation error: syntax error line 18 at position 4 unexpected'RES'.


syntax error line 18 at position 4 unexpected 'RES'.


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FAIR_PROC(
    DATABASE_REF VARCHAR
    , RUN_ID INTEGER
    , TASKID VARCHAR
    , RECORD_UPDATED NUMBER
    , RECORD_INSERTED NUMBER
    , RECORD_DELETED NUMBER)
RETURNS VARCHAR 
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
DECLARE 
V_PROCEDURE_NAME VARCHAR(50) := 'FAIR_PROC';
V_TASK_METRICS_TBL_REF VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
    V_TASK_METRICS_TBL_REF := :DATABASE_REF || '.METADATA_OPS.TASK_METRICS';
    LET RES RESULTSET;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    RES := (INSERT INTO IDENTIFIER(:V_TASK_METRICS_TBL_REF)(RUN_ID
        , TASKID 
        , RECORD_UPDATED
        , RECORD_INSERTED
        , RECORD_DELETED) 
    VALUES(:RUN_ID
        , :TASKID 
        , :RECORD_UPDATED
        , :RECORD_INSERTED
        , :RECORD_DELETED));
    COMMIT;
    RETURN 'SUCCESS';
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHER THEN
     ROLLBACK;
END;


Origin problem occurred in other proc where I was doing merge and collecting metrices for updated and inserted records using resultset. I understand that resultset has no benefit, it is just sample.
Any clue why this error should be thrown and how to avoid it?
Remove begin transaction like mentioned in code which is in the top. No error and records gets inserted. It's appears only if I put resultset with in begin transaction
I think, question is precise and can be reproduced easily but stack overflow prompts error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." to post this question
Following content is meaningless and has no relation to my question, it is just to fill up space.

Try putting a semi-colon at the end of the BEGIN TRANSACTION line

I hit the very bottom, I can't be more silliest :) thanks
